# How do I use objects/actions?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I have an action and an object created and it's working but I think I don't understand the params.  My action is "took".

Right now it says: `Joe Blow took a Red marker using Cool Photo App`.
I want it to say: `Joe Blow took a photo using Cool Photo App`.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?  I am read all of the docs but something just isn't clicking.

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: Is your verb 'took a'? it should probably be 'took' so that both formats make sense - both are used in FB's interface so both the object type name and the individual object titles should make sense - the 'a' or 'an' will be put in as necessary by Facebook

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have named the action as "take". facebook takes care of tenses. 
and to publish as took a photo, the title tag in your object should have value "Photo".